# Cannot start the rails debugger (using rails 3.1.3 with ruby 1.9.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

In a completely new test rails app, I enter:

```
$ sudo gem install ruby-debug19
$ bundle install
# and add the following line to my Gemfile
gem 'ruby-debug19', "~> 0.11.6"
$ rails server --debugger
```

I receive the following error

```
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
```

I have tried a dozen variations.  What am I missing??

Comment: Run bundle install again. According to your example you changed the Gemfile after running bundle install.

Comment: Thanks.  This is just poor editing on my part.  sadly I did do a bundle install after...  I think that the debugger is simply not compatible with ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (see https://github.com/chuckg/chuckg.github.com/blob/master/ruby/193_and_rdebug.md):

```
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => false
  gem 'ruby-debug-base19', :git => 'https://github.com/tribune/ruby-debug-base19.git', :require => false
  gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git@github.com:chuckg/linecache19.git', :branch => "0_5_13/dependencies", :require => false
```

If not working, go back to ruby 1.9.2 and try

> gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => "ruby-debug"